# How to get the value of Edittext present in a popup window

Tags: android, android-popupwindow

First of all,i've checked a couple of threads asking about this very same thing,and according to my understanding it seems i need to inflate a seperate view in the same method i'm going to use .getText() and also typecaste the same,but it doesn't seem to work,correct me if i'm wrong.

This is my  OnClick where i'm trying to get the Edittext value

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    LayoutInflater inflater1 = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    root1 = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.main_root);
    View popupContentView1 = inflater1.inflate(R.layout.codepopup, root1, false);

    code = (EditText) popupContentView1.findViewById(R.id.codeEt);
    btnauthorize = (Button)popupContentView1.findViewById(R.id.btnAuth);
    btnauthorize.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnfree =(Button)popupContentView1.findViewById(R.id.btnFree);
    btnfree.setOnClickListener(this);

    String temp;
    Intent intent;
    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.btnAccess:
            showPopup(popupContentView1, root, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            break;

        case R.id.btnAuth:
          final String cd = code.getText().toString();
            if(pwd != null) {
               if (code.getText().toString() == pwd) {
                   showToast("Authorization is Successful!");
                    signup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                   login.setEnabled(true);
                   if(active!=null)
                   {
                       active.dismiss();
                       active=null;
                   }
               }
               else{showToast("Please enter a valid Code!");signup.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); }
           }
            break;
```

Please let me know if i'm missing something,i'm getting "" in cd,any inputs would be helpfull

Comment: Hey Sam compare your string like this >>>  cd.equals(pwd);

Comment: get what you are trying to imply,but thats not issue,i even used a toast to display (code.getText().toString()) and it still shows ""

Comment: I am saying is that you are compare string in wrong way. Some time it may generate error. So it's good to use .equals()

Comment: Where are you creating the popup window? It is "" because the editText has no text.

Comment: @Ali the popupwindow is getting created in btnAccess,i've used a method called as showPopup

Comment: @HarinKaklotar i know,but i need to figure this out first

Comment: Move editText, Buttons initializations and their onClickListeners below showPopup() method and then try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the editText and Button(s) initializations and setonClickListeners below showPopup() method.

```
@Override public void onClick(View v) { 
    LayoutInflater inflater1 = LayoutInflater.from(this); 
    root1 = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.main_root); 
    View popupContentView1 = inflater1.inflate(R.layout.codepopup, root1, false);  
    String temp; Intent intent; 
    switch (v.getId()) { 
         case R.id.btnAccess: 
              showPopup(popupContentView1, root, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0); 
              code = (EditText) popupContentView1.findViewById(R.id.codeEt); 
              btnauthorize = (Button) popupContentView1.findViewById(R.id.btnAuth); 
              btnauthorize.setOnClickListener(this); 
              btnfree =(Button)popupContentView1.findViewById(R.id.btnFree); 
              btnfree.setOnClickListener(this); 
         break; 
         case R.id.btnAuth: 
              final String cd = code.getText().toString(); 
              if(pwd != null) { 
                   if (code.getText().toString() == pwd) { 
                        showToast("Authorization is Successful!"); 
                        signup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
                        login.setEnabled(true); 
                             if(active!=null) { 
                                  active.dismiss(); 
                                  active=null; 
                             } 
                   } else {
                   showToast("Please enter a valid Code!");
                   signup.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); } 
              } 
         break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Forgive indentation: Posted from stackoverflow android app.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
code.getText().toString() == pwd
```

to

```
code.getText().toString().equals(pwd)
```

Comment: I get what you are trying to imply,but thats not issue,i even used a toast to display (code.getText().toString()) and it still shows ""

Answer (score 0):

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    LayoutInflater inflater1 = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    root1 = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.main_root);
    View popupContentView1 = inflater1.inflate(R.layout.codepopup, root1, false);

```
btnauthorize = (Button)popupContentView1.findViewById(R.id.btnAuth);
btnauthorize.setOnClickListener(this);
btnfree =(Button)popupContentView1.findViewById(R.id.btnFree);
btnfree.setOnClickListener(this);

String temp;
Intent intent;
switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.btnAccess:
        showPopup(popupContentView1, root, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        break;

    case R.id.btnAuth:
      final String cd = code.getText().toString();
        if(pwd != null) {
            code = (EditText) popupContentView1.findViewById(R.id.codeEt);
           if (code.getText().toString().equals(pwd)) {
               showToast("Authorization is Successful!");
                signup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               login.setEnabled(true);
               if(active!=null)
               {
                   active.dismiss();
                   active=null;
               }
           }
           else{showToast("Please enter a valid Code!");signup.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); }
       }
        break;
```

Comment: I get what you are trying to imply,but thats not the issue,i even used a toast to display (code.getText().toString()) and it still shows ""